# Pandas dataframe transpose, to_csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

In the code below, in line 4 I can transpose the dataframe, but in line 5, when I use to_csv, the new CSV file is created, it remains the original version and not the transposed one. 
What might have gone wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('~/N.csv')

df2 = df.T

df2 = df.to_csv('~/N_transposed.csv')
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you expect to get back a dataframe from the df.to_csv() command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need to use df2 =

This is enough..

```
df2.to_csv('~/N_transposed.csv')
```

Answer (score 4):

In line 5, use

```
df3 = df2.to_csv('~/N_transposed.csv')
```

or

```
 df2.to_csv('~/N_transposed.csv')
```

The `df` variable has not been altered, the result is stored in `df2` and that's what you need to output to csv, not `df.to_csv`.

Comment: @ap235711 Well I see you've already accepted another answer. Cool then ☺